# Acknowledging funds from an award tied to a specific individual

Tags: conference, funding

I am organizing a conference at a major University. Much of the funding for the conference has come from the an Andrew W. Mellon Foundation award received by a particular scholar. He controls the funds tied to the award and has chosen to give some funding to support the conference. Should this be acknowledged on the advertising material associated with the conference? What wording should I use, if so? It looks strange to me to include the name of the academic, viz. "This conference has been made possible by Prof. X", but if I simply say "This conference has been made possible by the generosity of the Andrew W. Mellon Foundation", this gives the impression that they directly funded the conference, which is not the case.

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Have you asked Prof. X already?

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this kind of acknowledgement. It was phrased something like "We are grateful to Prof. X for supporting the conference through his Andrew W. Mellon Foundation funding.".